# How to enble SASL Authentiation Layer on Zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm new to Zookeeper. I have created a node in the zookeeper server in standalone mode. Here is the code snippet for that.

```
public Connect(String hostPort, String znode, String filename) throws KeeperException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    this.filename = filename;
    zk = new ZooKeeper(hostPort, 3000, this);

    zk.create(znode, new byte[0],
            ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.PERSISTENT);
}
```

Now I want to give authentication requirements using SASL in DIGEST-MD5 mode when I create the node (in the above code). I have successfully configured required [configurations](https://cwiki.apache.org/ZOOKEEPER/zookeeper-and-sasl.html) in the Zookeeper server hosted and have not configured in the Client.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to enable sasl authentication for zookeeper nodes.
Here is the code I used.

```
zk.addAuthInfo("digest", "admin:admin".getBytes());
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right. that looks more like normal auth.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/Zookeeper+and+SASL has more info on sasl